# Cannot get ng-model binding value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm using ionic to build a webapp, and I want to use ng-model bind input form value.

It is weird that I am **not getting** **model.cellphone's** value, but I **got** **model.password's** value.

Currently I cannot figure this out. Can anybody help me?

**html:**

```
    <ion-view>
      <ion-content class="login-content">
         <div class="login-form">
            <input type="text" class="login-form-cellphone" ng-model="model.cellphone" placeholder="please input your phonenumber" required minlength="11" maxlength="11"/>
            <input type="password" class="login-form-password" ng-model="model.password" placeholder="please input your password" required/>
            <button class="login-form-btn" ng-click="login()">Login</button>
            </div>
       </ion-content>
   </ion-view>
```

**js:**

```
   .controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', '$stateParams', 'RouteService', 'ApiService', function ($scope, $state, $stateParams, RouteService, ApiService) {
     var route = 'app.home.login';
     var params = $stateParams;
     $scope.model = {};

     $scope.doRefresh = function () {
     $scope.isChecked = true;
     };

     $scope.goBack = function () {
     $state.go(params.previewRoute);
     };

     $scope.clickCheck = function () {
     $scope.isChecked = !$scope.isChecked;
     };

     $scope.login = function () {
       console.log($scope.model.cellphone, $scope.model.password, $scope.isChecked);
       if (!$scope.model.cellphone) {
          console.log('cellphone');
          return;
       }
       if (!$scope.model.password) {
          console.log('password');
          return;
       }
       if (!$scope.isChecked) {
          console.log('isChecked');
          return;
       }
       ApiService.login(
         $scope.model.cellphone,
         $scope.model.password,
         null,
         function (status) {
           if (status === 1)
             $state.go(params.previewRoute);
       })
     };
```

Comment: What happens if you set $scope.model.cellphone = 01234567890 in controller ? Do you get same value in form ? make sure the length is 11.

Comment: I did, and the wired thing is $scope.model.cellphone cannot get value but $scope.model.password can!

Comment: oh, my careless ! thanks a lot!